# Visual Studio: Add UWP Windows.ApplicationModel.Store to non-UWP Project

Tags: delphi, uwp, in-app-purchase, windows-10-universal, desktop-bridge

Is it possible to add Windows Store in-app purchase capability to a non-Universal Windows Platform (UWP) .NET project (class library .dll project) in Visual Studio 2017?

**Background:** I have an Inno Setup installer for a Delphi project that converts with Microsoft's Desktop App Converter (from the Desktop Bridge project).  I would like to enable in-app purchase capability by adding the `Windows.ApplicationModel.Store` namespace and purchase logic to a .NET assembly created as a [RemObjects Hydra](http://hydra.remobjects.com/hydra/) plugin.  By doing this, my Delphi app can perform in-app purchases using the Hydra plugin.

If there's a better solution for implementing Windows Store in-app purchases with a Classic Windows App (CWA) that has been converted with the Desktop App Converter, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to add Windows Store in-app purchase capability to a
>   non-Universal Windows Platform (UWP) .NET project (class library .dll
>   project) in Visual Studio 2017?

Yes. However, according to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/in-app-purchases-and-trials-using-the-windows-applicationmodel-store-namespace) of `Windows.ApplicationModel.Store`:

> The `Windows.ApplicationModel.Store` namespace is not supported in
>   Windows desktop applications that use the Desktop Bridge. These
>   applications must use the `Windows.Services.Store` namespace to
>   implement in-app purchases and trials.

Besides, the [Windows.Services.Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/in-app-purchases-and-trials#api_intro) namespace is also designed to have better performance.

By the way, for Desktop Bridge app, you might need to add additional code when you use `StoreContext` class to implement in-app purchase in your project. If your app has a window handle associated with rendering framework, you need to specify which application windows is the owner windows for modal dialogs shown by the object.

For the details of steps, you can refer to **[Using the StoreContext class with Desktop Bridge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/in-app-purchases-and-trials#desktop)**.

Comment: Thank you.  I was hoping to support Windows 10 users prior to 1607 (August 2016), but it looks as though this is not supported with Desktop Bridge.  It looks like I might have some trouble with the "owner window" of the StoreContext from within a Hydra plugin, but perhaps that's for another post.

Comment: Also, setting up access to the Windows 10 APIs from non-UWP context: https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/01/25/calling-windows-10-apis-desktop-application/